# Problem with getAttribute() and setAttributeNode()

Tags: javascript, html

Recently I created my first Python library called htam. So, now I'm trying to create an HTML page to practice HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, showing all htam updates.
To make a more efficient code I tried to use a JavaScript for loop to create an internal link for each version of htam.

In my HTML file I have:

```
<p id = "versions">
    <script src = "main.js"></script>
</p>
```

In my main.js file I have:

```
var h = 'htam ';
var versions = [
    '1.2.2',
    '1.2.0',
    '1.1.0',
    '1.0.4',
    '1.0.1',
    '1.0.0'
]

for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
    document.write("<strong>>>></strong> ")

    var newa = document.createElement("a");
    var att = document.createAttribute("href")
    var atext = document.createTextNode(h + versions[i]);

    att.value = "#" + versions[i]

    newa.appendChild(atext);
    newa.getAttribute(att);

    var element = document.getElementById("versions");
    element.appendChild(newa);
    element.getAttribute(att)

    document.write("<br>")
}
```

This code prints

[image: This]

and that's what I wanted, but these links are not clickable.

So, I changed getAttribute() with setAttributeNode():

```
var h = 'htam ';
var versions = [
    '1.2.2',
    '1.2.0',
    '1.1.0',
    '1.0.4',
    '1.0.1',
    '1.0.0'
]

for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
    document.write("<strong>>>></strong> ")

    var newa = document.createElement("a");
    var att = document.createAttribute("href")
    var atext = document.createTextNode(h + versions[i]);

    att.value = "#" + versions[i]

    newa.appendChild(atext);
    newa.setAttributeNode(att);

    var element = document.getElementById("versions");
    element.appendChild(newa);
    element.setAttributeNode(att)

    document.write("<br>")
}
```

This one print

[image: this_2]

which is a clickable and perfectly working internal link, but it prints just the first object of the list.

How can I get the first result but with all clickable links?

Comment: Not that you should really escape characters like `<` and `>` in HTML, since HTML uses those characters themselves. Most HTML parsers will do the right thing, but since it's easy to just write `&gt;` instead of `>` you might as well. Also, avoid `document.write`, and especially avoid mixing `document.write` and `document.createElement`. Prefer the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the call `element.setAttributeNode(att)`. An `Attr` can only be added to one element; trying to add the same attribute to another element causes an error and the script stops.

There's no need to add the `href` attribute to the `versions` element in the first place. It's only needed on the `a`. Remove this unnecessary call and you get all the links.

```js
var h = 'htam ';
var versions = [
    '1.2.2',
    '1.2.0',
    '1.1.0',
    '1.0.4',
    '1.0.1',
    '1.0.0'
]

for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
    document.write("<strong>>>></strong> ")

    var newa = document.createElement("a");
    var att = document.createAttribute("href")
    var atext = document.createTextNode(h + versions[i]);

    att.value = "#" + versions[i]

    newa.appendChild(atext);
    newa.setAttributeNode(att);

    var element = document.getElementById("versions");
    element.appendChild(newa);

    document.write("<br>")
}
```

```html
Versions
<div id="versions">

</div>
```

In practice, no one actually uses `createAttribute` and `setAttributeNode`. It's more normal to use

```
newa.setAttribute("href", h + versions[i]);
```

or

```
newa.href = h + versions[i];
```

Comment: You could even simplify further and just set the `href` property `newa.href = "#" + versions[i];` instead of dealing with attribute nodes at all; the rendered result will be the same.